# Problems Passing value from highestbars() into lowestbars()

Tags: types, casting, pine-script

.

My goal is to determine the bar location of the `lowest-low` since the `highest-high[lookback]`.

I have no idea why it is not possible to plug the value of `hb` into `lowestbars()`, although my sense is that `highestbars()` is creating a variable type that is unacceptable to `lowestbars()` ?

```
lookback = input(100)

hb  = -highestbars(high, lookback)

lb  = -lowestbars(low, hb)
```

Insofar as I understand, `hb = -highestbars(high, lookback)` simply returns an `int` that is the offset of the specified `(source, length)`.

I have also verified this in the data window by plotting

```
plotchar(hb, title="hb",char="")`

plotchar(lb, title="lb",char="")`
```

That being the case, why is it not possible to simply pass the value of `hb` into `lowestbars()` ?

If I attempt `lowestbars(low, 5)` for example I have no problem.   But `lowestbars(low, hb)`—which appears to have the same form—somehow causes `lowestbars()`to calculate `hb` as it if were `na`.

Unfortunately, `lowestbars(low, int(hb) )` and other similar attempts were not successful.

On a similar note, is it somehow possible in Pine Script to determine what `type` a variable has, the way one can in javascript:

```
var str = "this is string";

typeof str; // returns string
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because some built in functions can't accept a time series variable as input, which hb is, a series int as opposed to a var int or input int.

```
lookback = input(30)

int h_offset = 0
float hh = high
int l_offset = 0
float ll = low

for i = 1 to lookback - 1
    if high[i] > hh
        hh := high[i]
        h_offset := i

for j = 1 to h_offset
    if low[j] < ll
        ll := low[j]
        l_offset := j


hh_lab = label.new(x = bar_index - h_offset, y = hh, style = label.style_label_down)
label.delete(hh_lab[1])
ll_lab = label.new(x = bar_index - l_offset, y = ll, style = label.style_label_up)
label.delete(ll_lab[1])
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to get the variable type in Pine Script?  It seems my suspicion was correct, but I didn't have a way of verifying what variable types were being used.

Comment: Not via code. For built in functions you can get the type from the man page ie for highestbars it will tell you : highestbars(source, length) → series[integer]. Otherwise for your own variables you can explicitly declare their type to make it clearer eg. var int lookback = 5

Comment: Yeh, I was really hoping for a coded version.  Specifically so that I would be able to verify the type of a variable in case it was somehow re-cast along the way.  Thanks again, in any case, for your solution to the original problem.